# Convert string to date SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

My source table has records in `dmy` and `mdy` format in a single column and is of `nvarchar` datatype. How can I convert this data to `datetime` and extract month from each record?

```
Source Data
StartDate: 06/13/2018,
           30/05/2018

Expected result:
Month:6
      5
```

Comment: Do you have a column that notes if the date is dmy or mdy? If the answer is no, then the answer to your question is also no (or not reliably). Without knowledge of the format, is the value `'12/01/2017'` 12 January 2017 or 01 December 2017? Also store your data in a datatype appropriate for what it is. Not using the correct data type can (and will) put you in a position like this and makes all of it completely useless.

Comment: @Larnu it needs to be shouted so it doesn't happen

Comment: You need to know the format per entry. Otherwise you can only reliably convert only those where day = month. (or those where day values > 12)

Comment: Nope...you are stuck with bad data because the decision to store dates as strings is a bad one. Be very careful to [choose the correct datatype](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) and this kind of thing is not an issue.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint, I want to work where you do, where no one ever hands you junk data and says, "Here. You're stuck with it."

Comment: @WhatsThePoint it would be far more effective communication to explain why that is such a horrible idea instead of just saying "don't do it". While I agree with your point the delivery is less effective than it could be.

Comment: Are there any other info on other columns that would make the format clear for particular row?

Comment: @EricBrandt at my place its good data, junk processes tbh

Answer (score 1):

Like has been discussed in the comments, without knowing what format the date is in the data is effectively useless. Although I'm providing an answer, the column names are very important. **One is called Guessed because that is what it is, a guess.**

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('13/01/2018','gb'),
                ('12/01/2018','gb'),
                ('12/01/2018','us'),
                ('04/27/2018','us'),
                ('04/05/2018','us')) V(D,f))
SELECT *,
       CONVERT(datetime,V.D, CASE V.F WHEN 'us' THEN 101 WHEN 'gb' THEN 103 END) AS ActualDate,
       DATEPART(MONTH,CONVERT(datetime,V.D, CASE V.F WHEN 'us' THEN 101 WHEN 'gb' THEN 103 END)) AS ActualMonth,
       CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(datetime,V.D,103) IS NULL THEN TRY_CONVERT(datetime,V.D,101) ELSE TRY_CONVERT(datetime,V.D,103) END AS GuessedDate,
       DATEPART(MONTH,CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(datetime,V.D,103) IS NULL THEN TRY_CONVERT(datetime,V.D,101) ELSE TRY_CONVERT(datetime,V.D,103) END) AS GuessedMonth
FROM VTE V;
```

Notice that these queries get very different results, and in the guessed columns, 2 are **wrong**.

Personally, I suggest you fix your data type first. If you can't **reliably** tell which date format the data is in *it's lost*.The only ones you'll be able to tell if they are in a particular format is if one of the first 2 values has a value equal or greater than 13 (for example `'13/12/2018'` must be dmy format, and `'05/27/2017'` must be mdy). For the guess, I went with dmy being the "default" format. You *might* know your data better than that (and assume mdy is the default), however, considering the data choice I imagine your guess is as good as anyones.

Good luck anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column that identifies the format, go with @Lamu's approach. Otherwise, you can examine the date fields: If either the first or second field is > 12, you know that field is the day. If we assume that all the records are in the format `X/Y/Z`, where Z is the year, and X and Y are the month and day (or day and month), we can do something like this:

```
WITH
    -- sample data: we can infer the format from the first 2 records ,
    -- but not the last
    SourceData(ds) AS
    (
        SELECT '6/13/2018' UNION ALL
        SELECT '30/05/2018' UNION ALL
        SELECT '12/01/2017'
    )
    ,WithSlashPositions(ds, Slash1_Position, Slash2_Position) AS
    (
        SELECT 
            ds, 
            CHARINDEX('/', ds, 1),
            CHARINDEX('/', ds, CHARINDEX('/', ds, 1) + 1)
        FROM SourceData
    )
    ,WithFields(ds, Slash1_Position, Slash2_Position, f1, f2, f3) AS
    (
        SELECT *,
            CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(ds, 1, Slash1_Position - 1)),
            CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(ds, Slash1_Position + 1, Slash2_Position - Slash1_Position - 1)),
            CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(ds, Slash2_Position + 1, LEN(ds)))
        FROM WithSlashPositions
    )
SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN f1 > 12 -- we know f1 is the day
            THEN CONVERT(DATE, ds, 103)
        WHEN f2 > 12 -- we know f2 is the day
            THEN CONVERT(DATE, ds, 101)
    END AS guess
FROM WithFields
```

returning these records:

```
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+----+----+------+------------+
|     ds     | Slash1_Position | Slash2_Position | f1 | f2 |  f3  |    guess   |
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+----+----+------+------------+
| 6/13/2018  |               2 |               5 |  6 | 13 | 2018 | 2018-06-13 |
| 30/05/2018 |               3 |               6 | 30 |  5 | 2018 | 2018-05-30 |
| 12/01/2017 |               3 |               6 | 12 |  1 | 2017 | NULL       |
+------------+-----------------+-----------------+----+----+------+------------+
```

Note that the last record (`12/01/2017`) returns null, because we can't infer its format.